# React - to manipulate DOM or use state?

Tags: reactjs

This Is more of a "theoretical" question that often buffles me in different situations and use cases, I will give a simple example to demonstrate it.

Let's say I have a list of 10 buttons.
Everrytime I click a button, a floating menu appears on top of the clicked button - there is only one menu visible for any given time.
Let's assume that I can't render this floating menu within the button component and I can only render it in the buttons parent level (meaning that this menu is sibling to those buttons).

I have 2 possible options to do that:

1. Keep the  x,y position of the last clicked button and render the menu in this given position
2. Render the menu once and using "ref" to directly relocate the menu

On the one hand, the first approach seems more "Reactish". On the other hand, the possible implemention I can think of is pretty ugly (capturing the clicked item position and saving it to state which triggers defender), and further more, I am not so sure about re re rendering the whole container just because I need to move a small piece of it.

The second approach touches the DOM directly using refs. Although possible , doing DOM manipulations sometimes feel bad to me.

Is there a better approach? Which of the 2 makes more sense?

Any suggestion or thoughts will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React uses whats called a virtual DOM, which is a representation of the DOM,  that sits on top of the real browser DOM. Whenever you update state or a user performs an action the virtual DOM compares and checks the changes with the real DOM and then updates the UI accordingly.

So if certain DOM elements like a  are not different between changes it does not get re rendered, only the DOM elements that have changed are re rendered. And if a property on a DOM element is changed, only the property is updated and the DOM element is not re rendered.

```
<div color="blue" />
```

to

```
<div color="red" />
```

The whole element is not destroyed and re created, only the property is changed.

However if the element in the host tree is different than the entire host tree is destroyed and recreated.

```
<div />
```

to

```
<p>
```

This is refereed to as reconciliation 
https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

So using refs is definitely more of a hacky solution since its more of an escape hatch and directly manipulates the DOM.

I would definitely stick with option 1, I think there is an elegant solution to the use case you described, it would involve just adding a click event listener in the componentDidMount and keeping track of the click position that way.

And also its hard to say without code but since your buttons will be the same, they will not be re rendered only the menu will.

Would recommend for further reading 
https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/